# Plugin Stopped working with JQuery 1.9.1

Tags: jquery

Some time ago I created a Balloon plugin using JQuery 1.8.3.

When I updated from JQuery 1.8.3 to JQuery 1.9.1 my plugin stoped working.

The balloons do not show anymore. I went back to 1.8.3 and it works.

I tried to understand what might be wrong but I can't find it.

Could someone, please, help me out? This is my code:

```
    (function ($) {
      $.fn.Balloon = function (options) {
    var defaults = {
          balloon: "",
          class: "Balloon",
          click: false,
          id: "Balloon",
          sensible: false,
          x: -4,
          y: -40
        };
        var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        var balloon;
        $(this).each(function () {
          var title = $(this).attr("title");
          if (title == undefined) return;
          $(this).hover(function (e) {
            $(this).removeAttr("title")
            balloon = "<div id='{id}' class='{class}'><span class='Text'>{content}</span><span class='Background'></span></div>"
            if (options.balloon == "") {
              balloon = balloon.replace("{class}", options.class).replace("{id}", options.id).replace("{content}", title);
            } else {
              balloon = balloon.replace("{class}", options.class).replace("{id}", options.id).replace("{content}", options.balloon).replace("{title}", title);
            }
            $("body").append(balloon);
            $("#" + options.id).fadeIn("fast");
          },
          function () {
            $("#" + options.id).remove();
            $(this).attr("title", title);
          });
          $(this).mousedown(function (e) {
            if (options.click) {
              $("#" + options.id).remove();
              $(this).attr("title", title);
            }
          }),
          $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
            var x = e.pageX + options.x;
            var y = e.pageY + options.y;
            if (options.sensible) {
              var width = $("#" + options.id).width();
              var height = $("#" + options.id).height();
              var right = $(window).width() - (x + width);
              var bottom = $(window).height() - (y + height);
              if (right < 20) {
                x = e.pageX - width - options.x;
              }
              if (bottom < 20) {
                y = e.pageY - height - options.y;
              }
            }
            $("#" + options.id).css({ top: y, left: x });
          }); // Mouse Move
        }); // Balloon
      };
    })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it replacing hover by:

```
$(this).mouseenter(function (e) {
  // Code
}),
$(this).mouseleave(function (e) {
  // Code
});
```

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 2):

Use [jQuery Migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme) to find out what you need to fix for jQuery 1.9.

> This plugin can be used to detect and restore APIs or features that
>   have been deprecated in jQuery and removed as of version 1.9. See the
>   [warnings page](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/master/warnings.md) for more information regarding messages the plugin
>   generates. For more information about the changes made in jQuery 1.9,
>   see the [upgrade guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/) and [blog post](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/15/jquery-1-9-final-jquery-2-0-beta-migrate-final-released/).
>
> In your web page, load this plugin after the script for jQuery:
>
> ```
> <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
> <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You mention a writing a plugin. Take a look at http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/ to see the changes jQuery 1.9 brought. There are a bunch of breaking changes they made.

I would use the jQuery Migrate plugin to identify the problems, but do not use it in production. You should make your plugin work with jQuery 1.9+.